# Copiar conteúdo de um div ao clicar em um botão

Tags: jquery

Tenho um encurtador de URL, onde há listagem com todos os links gerados.
O que eu preciso, é criar um botão ao lado, em que, quando a pessoa clique em cima dele, copie automaticamente a div que contém o link encurtado.

Tô tentando algo assim:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = document.getElementById("btCopia").innerHTML;
}
```

O HTML está assim

```
<div id="link">teste1.1</div>
<div id="btCopia">COPIAR</div>
```

A sintaxe não está Ok, alguém já fez algo parecido, talvez com Jquery?

Comment: Pode postar a parte HTML relevante?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Felipe: queres copiar `teste1.1` e mudar o `COPIAR` para ser `teste1.1`? tens outros campos onde queres fazer o mesmo? com ids também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite, talvez eu esteja falando mais do mesmo mas acho válido ressaltar que, levando em consideração o fato do Felipe não apresentar no código dele o uso de Jquery, e o Anmaia recomendar, gostaria de propor só mais dois detalhes na proposta do Anmaia, sendo eles:

1 - Incluir o CDN na sua pagina:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

2 - A inclusão do Ready do Jquery no código de exemplo:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
      $("#btCopiar").on("click", function(){
          $("#link").text($("#paraCopiar").text());
      });
 });
 </script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

No mais acho que é só isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer o mesmo com jQuery é o seguinte:

```
$("#link").text($("#btCopia").text())
```

Esse trecho de código vai copiar o valor de `btCopia` para `link`.

**Sugestão**

Modifique o seu html e javascript para capturar isso de uma forma mais fácil. Você está usando o onload em seu javascript, talvez o código a seguir melhore sua implementação:

```
<div id="link">[Valor do link]</div>
<div id="paraCopiar">[Esse valor deve ser copiado para #link]</div>

<button id="btCopiar">Copiar</button>

<script>

$("#btCopiar").on("click", function(){
   $("#link").text($("#paraCopiar").text());
});

</script>
```

Dessa forma, toda vez que você clicar no botão `btCopiar` o conteúdo de `paraCopiar` vai para `link`.

Comment: Apenas os elementos filhos do elemento que possui o id `btCopia`?

Comment: @Patrick veja se a sugestão em minha resposta te ajuda.